# How to count words in a corpus document

Tags: python, nltk

I want to know the best way to count words in a document. If I have my own "corp.txt" corpus setup and I want to know how frequently "students, trust, ayre" occur in the file "corp.txt". What could I use?

Would it be one of the following:

```
....
full=nltk.Text(mycorpus.words('FullReport.txt'))
>>> fdist= FreqDist(full)
>>> fdist
<FreqDist with 34133 outcomes>
// HOW WOULD I CALCULATE HOW FREQUENTLY THE WORDS 
"students, trust, ayre" occur in full.
```

Thanks,
Ray

Comment: Neither one of those are provided by the standard python library. Are you sure you're not thinking of NLTK?

Comment: Looking at your name, i'm gonna pretend that you know what "students trust ayre" means. Anyway, i would go with `FreqDist`. `fdist = FreqDist(); for word in tokenize.whitespace(sent): fdist.inc(word.lower())`. You can check the doc [here](http://nltk.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/api/nltk.probability.FreqDist-class.html).

Comment: I edited the answer please double check it for me. Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [How optimize word counting in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22849919/how-optimize-word-counting-in-python)

Answer (score 12):

I would suggest looking into collections.Counter. Especially for large amounts of text, this does the trick and is only limited by the available memory. It counted 30 billions tokens in a day and a half on a computer with 12Gb of ram. Pseudocode (variable Words will in practice be some reference to a file or similar):

```
from collections import Counter
my_counter = Counter()
for word in Words:
    my_counter.update(word)
```

When finished the words are in a dictionary my_counter which then can be written to disk or stored elsewhere (sqlite for example).

Comment: Note that Counter() can take a list as input, so if W is a list of words:
`counts = Counter(W)`
will do the trick

Answer (score 4):

Most people would just use a defaultdictionary (with a default value of 0). Every time you see a word, just increment the value by one:

```
total = 0
count = defaultdict(lambda: 0)
for word in words:
    total += 1
    count[word] += 1

# Now you can just determine the frequency by dividing each count by total
for word, ct in count.items():
     print('Frequency of %s: %f%%' % (word, 100.0 * float(ct) / float(total)))
```

Comment: You mean `defaultdict(int)` -- `defaultdict` takes a callable.

Comment: @Chris how about using `Counter`?

Answer (score 4):

You are almost there! You can index the FreqDist using the word you are interested in.
Try the following:

```
print fdist['students']
print fdist['ayre']
print fdist['full']
```

This gives you the count or number of occurrences of each word.
You said "how frequently" - frequency is different to number of occurrences - and that can got like this:

```
print fdist.freq('students')
print fdist.freq('ayre')
print fdist.freq('full')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can read a file and then tokenize and put the individual tokens into a `FreqDist` object in `NLTK`, see http://nltk.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/api/nltk.probability.FreqDist-class.html

```
from nltk.probability import FreqDist
from nltk import word_tokenize

# Creates a test file for reading.
doc = "this is a blah blah foo bar black sheep sentence. Blah blah!"
with open('test.txt', 'w') as fout:
    fout.write(doc)

# Reads a file into FreqDist object.
fdist = FreqDist()
with open('test.txt', 'r') as fin:
    for word in word_tokenize(fin.read()):
        fdist.inc(word)

print "'blah' occurred", fdist['blah'], "times"
```

[out]:

```
'blah' occurred 3 times
```

Alternatively, you can use a native `Counter` object from `collections` and you get the same counts, see https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html. Note that the keys in the FreqDist or Counter object are case sensitive, so you might also want to lowercase your tokenize:

```
from collections import Counter
from nltk import word_tokenize

# Creates a test file for reading.
doc = "this is a blah blah foo bar black sheep sentence. Blah blah!"
with open('test.txt', 'w') as fout:
    fout.write(doc)

# Reads a file into FreqDist object.
fdist = Counter()
with open('test.txt', 'r') as fin:
    fdist.update(word_tokenize(fin.read().lower()))

print "'blah' occurred", fdist['blah'], "times"
```